# how to validate many email in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, validation, email

I have many email in excel file, but i have problem,
many email must be validate, because missing @, . , and in the email there is a space or quote, and others,
i want in my right cell i can add false or true for right email, so i can filter or sort for fix that or you can gift me options to use others software

thanks before
sorry if my english language is bad

for example :

1. test@mail.com   true
2. test @mail.com  false
3. test@mail       false
4. test.mail       false
5. test@mail.com'  false

Comment: Use a Regex: http://www.msofficegurus.com/post/How-to-VBA-email-validation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=AND(ISERROR(MATCH("?*@?*.?*";A1;0))=FALSE;ISERROR(FIND(" ";A1)))`
will match your examples correctly (for cell A1).

Will validate any string which has no spaces and has 1/+ characters, then "@", then 1/+ characters, then ".", then 1/+ charaters.

Not perfect, but very lightweight!

Comment: thanks you so helpful, just point 5 can't be validate, but is ok, thank you so much